# Is there a setting that limits amount of parallel image resizes? When there are multiple images on a page performance is really slow

Tags: performance, mediaurls

On Sitecore 8.2 I have a situation where images are taking way longer than expected to get served by Sitecore.

Lets say I have a page with 10 images, all SVGs under 1kb.

- 3 images take 50ms
- 3 images take 500ms
- 4 take between 1 sec and 3 secs

If I then load one of these long loading media files on its own it will load almost instantly; this is why I feel it is related to multiple media requests at the same time.

I've tried with and without Dianoga and I can't see any suspicious activity in the logs.

xDb is disabled.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

What I expect is happening is that there are a lot of calls being generated by the page and that is slowing down images.

I am assuming all the images are in the Media Library. You can look at cache settings to make sure Media Cache is working fine and is not being cleared too soon. Check if it is enabled first through this setting

```
 <setting name="Media.CachingEnabled" value="false" />
```

All files after the first download should be stored in the media cache and subsequent calls should just download the file from the file system: https://sitecoreblog.patelyogesh.in/2014/04/how-sitecore-media-cache-is-works.html

Also make sure DisableBrowserCaching in the webconfig is set to false so the browser can cache these images. Check the headers on these images calls to make sure there is no "no-cache" set in the cache control header.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately all the things you've highlighted above look to be working as expected.

Comment: oh... that's a bummer. Are you seeing this with other types of files too? At this point, it is not sitecore. There's something else going on in the network. Look at IIS, WAF rules. Any other sites that behave the same being served from the same infrastructure?